# Is there any free software that helps to know specific charge densities or ELFs at any position of the material?

Tags: density-functional-theory, software-recommendations, visualization-software, charge-density, conceptual-dft

Can anyone suggest some free software that can visualize the charge density and/or electron localization function (ELF)? More importantly, can we determine/know those values (charge density and/or ELF) to any arbitrary position of the structure - i.e. not just the color map?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, for example the Python package [chemtools](https://chemtools.org/auto_examples/index.html#electron-localization-function-elf) gives several examples of calculating the ELF from a Gaussian cube or similar wavefunction file.

At the moment, it will generate a Gaussian-compatible cube, but you can interpolate to whatever point you want. (I haven't gone through the Python code in detail, but I suspect you could get the ELF or other metric at points without generating the cube.)

Comment: Thanks @Geoff. Does it calculate the charge densities as well (in addition to ELF)?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "charge density" - do you want the electron density (yes) or the electrostatic potential (yes). See the examples for the range of analysis.